# High CPU temperature and Fan speed in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: radeon, cpu, jupiter, fancontrol

I am using 12.04 LTS version of ubuntu. In which I am getting High CPU temperature and fan speed from beginning of the system. Temperature remain > 62°C. I am using jupitar but it's not helping in case of mine. Jupitar in power saving mode. And very low battery backup. Help me with this problem.

I am using hp pavilion dv6 - 6120tx
Processor   Intel Core i5-2410M
GPU Model   AMD Radeon HD 6490M

Comment: Please tell us your specs, otherwise we can't help you at all.

Comment: I edited my question. You may see it now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you didn't install drivers for your dGPU (your Radeon), here is what you have to do:

- You have to download the following packages:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6`

`sudo apt-get install dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases`

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-core libgcc1`

- If you're using a 64bit system, addditionally install these packages as well

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32gcc1 libc6-i386`

`cd /usr ; sudo ln -svT lib /usr/lib64`

- Download and install drivers

`cd ~/; mkdir catalyst12.10; cd catalyst12.10/`

`wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.10-x86.x86_64.zip`

`chmod +x amd-driver-installer-12-10-x86.x86_64.run`

`sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise`

`sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb`

`sudo aticonfig --initial -f`

- Reboot

If you are having problems with switching to your iGPU and Unity3D, you may have to change the /etc/X11/Xsession.d/10fglrx with root

`gksu gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/10fglrx`

If you are using a 32 bit system, the file has to look like this:

`LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/fglrx/dri 
if [`uname -m`= 'x86_64' ]; then 
if [ -d /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri ]; then 
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=${LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH}:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib32/dri
if [ ! -z $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
fi 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/usr/lib32 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
fi 
fi 
export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH`

If you are using a 64bit system, like this:

`LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/fglrx/dri 
if [`uname -m`= 'x86_64' ]; then 
if [ -d /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri ]; then 
LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=${LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH}:/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri
if [ ! -z $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ]; then 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
fi 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}/usr/lib32
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
fi 
fi 
export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH`

- Reboot

Comment: For future questions, have a look at this wiki http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide

Comment: but it's showing error. And i can't able to post the output of terminal here :(

Comment: What kind of error, I cannot guess what the problem might be!