# My average laptop temperature is 75C. Is it Normal?

Tags: 12.10, ati, overheating

I'm using Samsung 5 Series NP535U4X-S01ID with specification of AMD Quad-Core A8-4555M processor and AMD Radeon HD 7600G + HD 7550M Dual Graphics.

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I use the AMD nee ATI: Thames [Radeon 7500M/7600M Series] driver which is recommended by the ubuntu software sources.

But after I update to this AMD "recommended" driver, my average laptop temperature rise up to 75C. Is this normal? Or what should I do to reduce the average temperature?

(The fan sounds loud right now.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to turn off your Radeon GPU in order to resolve your problem with temperature and fan sound! I used that method on 12.04, 12.10 and is working perfectly.

Check [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103253/how-do-i-turn-off-the-radeon-gpu-ono-my-hp-pavilion-dm4) question also.

More informations about Hybrid Graphics [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics)

Comment: I like the http://askubuntu.com/questions/103253/how-do-i-turn-off-the-radeon-gpu-ono-my-hp-pavilion-dm4 link. The user42257 's answer answered my question here. 

Thank's Dave.

Answer (score 5):

Anything between 45-65 ° Celcius is fine if you working on regular applications and the number of application you are running is not abnormally high. However, even in such circumstances, the temperature may rise beyond this range due to dust or other underlying softwares or some other reasons I am not aware of.

If your system heats up regularly, try cleaning up your vents, near the fans which block air by either blowing air through it or using soft brushes.

Some applications like `Jupiter` help control temperature by adjusting system performance accordingly. See instructions for installing Jupiter [here](http://www.thelittleican.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-measure-temperature-of-your.html).

Comment: Thank's for your response Jobin. I have already installed the Jupiter application, but nothing has changed in the average temperature. It's still shown around 75C-80C.

Comment: As I said earlier, if you can compromise on the performance, `jupiter` has an option to put the system on "Power Saving Mode", which should reduce the temperature to around 40. The option to change mode is available in the drop-down menu when you click no the "thunder" icon available on the menu-bar.

Answer (score 2):

My laptop has 50-60 degrees of Celsius (older Asus eeePc with Atom CPU). Nowadays I'm using Intel Core i5 CPU on HP ProBook notebook and the temperature doesn't reach over 40 degrees. Sometimes the graphic chipset can make the temperature higher.

In case that you are using Linux try to monitor the mostly used processes with high system resources usage.

Answer (score 1):

I use ubuntu on a laptop too (a crappy one).
75 C is just fine, as long as it doesn't get over 90 (it will shut down your system,
and thus making it an unreliable system).
If you cant keep it at this temperature, you should try to look for what actually overheats it(in my case the cpu sometimes went up to 100C), then search for a fixing programm that lets you controll the speed of the overheating piece of hardware :)!

Cheers, Max

Comment: Thank you Max for your answer. I will keep that in mind to keep my laptop temperature under 90C.

Answer (score 1):

average temperature of my laptop is 50 to 55 degree Celsius.when no application is running then it comes down to 35 to 37 degree celsius and when my cpu usage reach up to 80% then my cpu temperature is 70 degree celsius...

Answer (score 1):

I had installed Core Temp after I began having some sudden black outs; after quickly figuring out the high temps were forcing the shutdowns, I began researching a fix for the problem and was afraid I would have to take the machine apart (which you end up doing to get to the fan) to fix it.

I ended up trying the most simple suggestion. I took a drinking straw and flattened one end, taped of half of the flattened end for a more stream line flow of air; popped a piece of bread in my mouth to get rid of all the moisture in my mouth; then blew both through the exhaust backwards, into the heat sink, and forward down through the fan vents.  I saw several plumes of dust when I blew from either direction, and when I turned my machine back on was amazed that it dropped from 80c to 35-40c while running processor taxing programs.  It's seemed like a miracle.

Apparently a vacuum is a bad choice for this fix, because of static electricity.  A vacuum conducts static electricity and can send it through your computer, though very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered a similar question, [check it out.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253771/high-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-in-ubuntu-12-04/253790#253790)

Otherwise, follow the official [documentation of ATI](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page) or this [great thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450)

I am pretty sure that's a driver issue unfortunately. Read those links through, I guess there is a possible solution to that, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response p00c. I've tried this official documentation from ATI, but I get confused about how to use this installation.

Comment: Were you thinking of using [this guide?](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29)

Comment: Well, I used the Max's solution p00c and it works.